# add data to firebase with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, post

i try to add data ("promo") to firestore  in nodejs but  get 404 error in postman even in the console i get nothing except  "Server is live @ http://localhost:5000"                                                        this is how i add the data

```
export async function AddPromo(req,res){
    const promo=req.body;
    console.log(promo);
    try{
      const dbRef = collection(basedb, "promotion");
      const docRef= await addDoc(dbRef, promo);
      res.status(200).send('promo created successfully');
    }
      catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
      }

  }
```

and this the rooute file

```
import { GetClientByuid } from '../Controllers/client.js';
import {AddPromo} from '../Controllers/promo.js';

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/client/:uid',GetClientByuid);
router.post('/addpromo',AddPromo);
export default router;
```

and here the app.js

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import config from './Config.js';
import RouteApp from './routes/RouteApp.js';

  const app = express(); 
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use('/api', RouteApp);
  
  app.listen(config.port, () =>
    console.log(`Server is live @ ${config.hostUrl}`),
  );
```

i'm sure that url in Postman matches the route defined
the url is : http://localhost:5000/api/addpromo
and in requested body i add this :
{"promo":{
"dateDebut":"2023-11-26",
"dateFin":"2023-11-29",
"plat": [{"key": 1695861225108,"plat":"Sandwich bey" ,"quantity":2},
{"key": 1695861252385,"plat":"Pizza cheese" ,"quantity":1}],
"remise":"15",
"restaurant":"SKks7BisGvhvO6WRkNKQxj98s3K3"
}
}

Comment: 404 is the ExpressJS/NodeJS engine stating that the URL you are trying to access is not handled.  This is a Node/Express configuration or usage issue.  Unrelated to Firebase at all.  Consider looking into ways to debug ExpressJS apps.

Comment: @GregFenton the url provided in postman similaire to the router in nodejs "router.post('/addpromo',AddPromo); "   and when i get data from firebase ,get is working fine , how can i  resolve it

Comment: I am confused by this information.  When do you get 404 and when do you not?

Comment: @GregFenton when i try to get data from firebase works fine but when i add data to firebase i get  "status 404 not found " "<pre>Cannot POST /api/addpromo%0A</pre>
"

Comment: Wait....you have "%0A" at the end of your POST URL ?  That is a url encoded newline character.

Again, the 404 is coming from Express.  This has nothing to do with Firebase.  Until you can get Express to service the request you are sending to it, your function is not running so this has nothing to do with the Firebase API calls in your handler...your handler is not finding the requested resource.

Comment: yyeah , now it works fine when i write it in new tab but why it added "%OA" and what means if you don't mind

Comment: @GregFenton if i want to implement an authentification  with react nativve , nodejs and firebase how can i organise the code i mean the code for creating a user resides in client side(react native) and the server side just for validation or not

Comment: The "%0A" means that somehow you added a newline character to the URL you were trying to access.  Maybe you pressed ENTER when typing in the URL value into a textarea input field?  (Textarea allow you to enter newlines, whereas textfields typically do not).

Comment: Your question about adding authentication to RN & Firebase is a totally new topic and one not really suitable to StackOverflow.  Maybe you want to join a Firebase discussion forum such as "Firebase Me" on discord or the "Firebase Community" Slack workspace?

I'll encourage you to consider: (1) use Expo for React-Native, and (2) use Firebase for the backend without the need for running your own NodeJS server.

See you on those community systems :)

Comment: @GregFenton one more question please , why  without  nodejs is that make the app more perform, i think the work will be "not organized" and  if i want to put the data into cashe server i mean apply the "client -cache - server" architecture  , in  this case should i use nodejs or not

Comment: You can, but that is a lot more work.  And until you *know* that you need an optimization (e.g. caching), then you should NOT be thinking about optimization.  Build something quickly, get it to market.  If the app is very popular but has scalability issues....that it the problem that you WANT to have.  Spending time building a super efficient app only to later find out nobody cares about it...that's a complete waste.

Comment: @GregFenton  the app should has scalability and  support the overload that is why i think it  must be optimized and that is not normal once  someone use the app , it will crashed

Comment: @GregFenton in this case  : the choice react native + firebase + nodejs is suitable or not

Comment: Do you KNOW that your app will be a huge success and thus need optimization, or are you HOPING that it will?

Regardless, Firebase is a very scalable Backend-As-A-Service in use by millions of apps.  Oh, and Firebase Cloud Functions is actually a Node engine that you can leverage as part of the BaaS.